# Bibliography style apacite: how to suppress month and day fields?

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I want to keep the month and day from showing up in bibliography references. I'm using `apacite`. Is there a way to suppress the two from being displayed without switching bibliography style and without manually deleting the `month` and `day` fields from the bib entries?

Comment: It should be easy to do with `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Bernard - It's not too difficult with the `apacite` citation management package either. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I don't know apacite well enoughto give this advice. For me, the main point is that biblatex is comparatively easy to customise, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress showing the contents of any `month` and `day` fields when using the `apacite` citation management package and `apacite` bibliography style, I suggest you issue the following command in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\APACrefYearMonthDay}[3]{\BBOP{#1}\BBCP}}
```

Notice that this command takes 3 arguments but ignores the second and third argument. I will let you form an educated guess as to what the first argument is about.